# Choosing SSL certificates in the UK

Tags: https

Recently Google announced that 50% of websites are secure. They have also been rumbling about demoting non-secure sites in the search rankings if they're not https.

So, how does one go about choosing a good and reasonably priced certificate issuer ? I've searched for online guides for this and most *seem* to be simply sites promoting one or two 'brands' of certificates. There also seem to be many 'resellers' and I don't want to choose one who's going to be going out of business.

Any help greatly appreciated...

(I realise that SSL like much of the web is global but a UK company would be better as all of my sites are based in the UK - actually, does that even make a difference?)

Comment: If your hosting provider is not providing letsencrypt certificates for free, it is time to find another host.

Comment: Sorry but the question in its current format is off-topic because it attracts recommendations which you can already see. Furthermore its likely duplicate because we already have similar questions such as [What to look for when choosing a SSL certificate provider](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/ssl-). You might be able to save your question by editing your question and being more specific rather than asking for help picking a provider, e.g My websites are hosted in UK data centres, does it matter if I purchase a SSL from a US provider etc? etc.

Comment: As far as businesses going out of business after providing you a service this is a risk taking any online service and the question is very opinionated... your never get 100% reassurance but generally as a good rule picking a bigger renowned company is less likely to go out of business because they most often find buyers whom buy them out before they go out of business.

Answer (score 1):

I depends what type of cert you want but if you want a basic SSL cert most of the major SSL issuers provide basic certs for around about 20STG. (I'm trying not to get into the opinion and recommendation side of things here but they are much of a muchness for basic certs). Also might be worth checking with your hosting provider who often provide certificates and will setup and install them for you as well as part of the purchase process.

Well worth checking out also now is Lets Encrypt who provide free SSL certs. Many control panels now have the ability to generate and install Lets Encrypt certificates as an option in them. This depends on your hosting provider/plan.

Definitely worth moving to SSL for a lot of reasons not least the one you mention, Google definitely is pushing for it (if not yet penalizing it).